# jQuery c3 chart show block instead of line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, c3.js

When I use c3.js for chart with d3.v3.min.js, it show chart with shadow block like this image

[image]

I want only with simple line without black area. Like this one.

How should I do? Please

[image]

## UPDATED

Here is my HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My Websit</title>
                  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/d3.v3.js"></script>
                  <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/c3.js"></script>
                  <script>
                        $(function(){
                            var chart = c3.generate({
                                bindto: '#chart',
                                data: {
                                  columns: [
                                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                                    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                                  ]
                                }
                            });
                        });
                  </script>   
    </head>
  <body>
      <div id="chart"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code (or) give us a fiddle link to check
?

Comment: Just set `fill: none` in the CSS or in the JS code.

Comment: Are you including the c3.css file as well?

Comment: Yes I am ,  I ready remove all css files @mgraham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously oriented in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544713/jquey-c3-chart-show-block-instead-of-line?noredirect=1#comment70294020_41544713), just set the `fill` to `none`:

```
path {
     fill: none;
 }
```

Or:

```
.c3-shape {
     fill: none;
 }
```

Here, I'm using the class `c3-shape` just to be more specific, because the axis is also a path.

Here is the demo:

```css
.c3-shape {
    fill: none;
}

.c3-axis path, .c3-axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>
                  <script>
                        $(function(){
                            var chart = c3.generate({
                                bindto: '#chart',
                                data: {
                                  columns: [
                                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                                    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
                                  ]
                                }
                            });
                        });
                  </script>   
  <body>
      <div id="chart"></div>
 </body>
```